# Unable to load Key pair from p12 certificate - OPENSSL error

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl, public-key-encryption

I try to extract public and private keys from PKCS#12 certificate with openssl and always have the same error, even i just want to see it without output file (with flag -info)

after the certificate himself i see this:

```
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2048
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 61 D1 40 34 84 2B 94 88 B1 77 23 C2 7F 46 30 DB 8C 4C 26 3A
    friendlyName: p12_name_iwn
Error outputting keys and certificates
22184:error:100D5010:elliptic curve routines:eckey_priv_decode:EC lib::0:
22184:error:0606F091:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKCS82PKEY:private key decode error::0:
error in pkcs12 `
```

I have separated private key from this certificate, exported from standard Microsoft Manager Console, in .pfx format, when i try to extract him to change it to .pem format, i still have the same error....

Openssl version I use :
`openssl-1.1.1c-win64`

Command:
`pkcs12 -in file.p12 -info`
(I used the same command with -outpu file.pem flag, but have the same issue)

Someone have solution for this, maybe? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please edit your question post to include the version of openssl you are using, and the exact openssl command-line syntax you were using to try to do this. Also, since .p12's include private keys, they are always supposed to be encrypted with a password. The fact that you didn't mention anything about using a password makes me wonder if you were trying to extract from it without providing the necessary password.

Comment: Oh, sorry, right, I edit the question, and of course password was entered, and I see the part of the certificate, but in keys part I have an error, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solved] It was WAPI technology, this one using different - not standard elliptic curve, so openssl can't work with it, need specific version on ssl called [GmSSL](http://gmssl.org/english.html)